Trying to understand Taylor series expansion of the roots of a polynomial involved in an elliptic integral
I am trying to understand the series for the expansion of the roots of a polynomial that appears in an Elliptic Integral in a paper.
The background is the following:
Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the polinomyal
$$
\mathcal{P}(x,j,h):=-2(1-x^2)(h+1-x)-j^2
$$ where $h$ and $j$ are real numbers. Let the roots of $P$ be denote by $\xi_i$ for $i=0,1,2$, where $-1\leq \xi_0\leq \xi_1\leq 1\leq \xi_2$.

Furthermore consider $k^2=\frac{\xi_1-\xi_0}{\xi_2-\xi_0}$.
One is able to write a certain Elliptic Integral depending on $\mathcal{P}$ as a sum of Complete Elliptic Integrals $K(k)$ and then we want to obtain certain series expansions.
The author wants to extend in the singular limit as $k \to 1$.
He sets $h\mapsto h\epsilon$ and $j_2\mapsto j_2\epsilon$ and expands in $\epsilon$.
The author claims that in this limit
\begin{align}
\xi_0 & = -1+\frac{1}{8}j^2+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)
\\ \xi_1 & = 1+\frac{1}{2}\left(h-\sqrt{h^2+j^2}\left(1-\frac{j^2}{8\sqrt{h^2+j^2}}\right)\right)+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)
\\ \xi_2 & = 1+\frac{1}{2}\left(h+\sqrt{h^2+j^2}\left(1+\frac{j^2}{8\sqrt{h^2+j^2}}\right)\right)+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)
\end{align}

I have been trying to obtain the same result but to no avail. I was wondering if anyone knows how to actually prove this.
My approach has been the following : use Mathematica, ask it to solve for the roots , obtain a function $\xi_0(j,h)$ that gives the root depending on $j$ and $h$ and then define  $\xi_0(\epsilon):=\xi_0(l\epsilon,h\epsilon)$ and then try to obtain the taylor series of this function at $\epsilon=0$. With this approach I don't get the result.
My second approach is write the root $\xi_j=d_0+d_1\epsilon+d_2\epsilon+...$
and then try to solve the equation iteratively $\frac{\partial}{\partial^i \epsilon}\mathcal{P}(\xi_j,\epsilon j, \epsilon h)=0$ iteratively in order to obtain the values of $d_i$. This seems to work for the root $\xi_0$ but not for $\xi_1$ or $\xi_2$.
If anyone knows what the approach is and the reasoning behind, it would be helpfull.
Thanks in advance.
